# Want to create a key value pair list from csv file but unable to

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, bottle, petl

I want to create a list of key-value pair with the output from /getService route.

I am able to filter the data that i wanted (Suburb and Services) from csv file vet_service_locations but want to have it as a key-value pair. Where keys are suburbs and services and values would be the relevant output.

I'm a beginner and tried different methods but nothing seems to work.

```
from bottle import html_quote, route, run, template, response, request
import petl as etl
from json import dumps
import csv


output = []

reading_file = etl.fromcsv('vet_service_locations.csv')
print(reading_file)


@route('/getServices')
def details():
    postcode = request.query.postcode
    print(postcode)
    for row in reading_file:
        if row[2] == postcode:
            output.append(row[1])
            output.append(row[4])
            
    print(output)
        
    

run(host='localhost', port=3000, debug=True)
```

[Vet_service_location.csv data image is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJ9i.png)

**Output I'm getting**

```
[('Adelaide', 'Small_Animal'), ('Adelaide', 'Oncology'), ('Adelaide', 'Surgery'), ('Adelaide', 'Annual_Checkup'), ('Adelaide', 'Wildlife')]
```

**Output I want**

```
 suburb, values 
[('Adelaide', 'Small_Animal'),  
('Adelaide', 'Oncology'),  
('Adelaide', 'Surgery'),  
('Adelaide', 'Annual_Checkup'),  
('Adelaide', 'Wildlife')]
```

So, kinda like the table, the same structure in which the vet_service_locations.csv is.

Comment: What does the data in `vet_service_locations.csv` look like?

Comment: hi, i have attach the link of image, have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Andrew's answer, try `pprint` to output the exact format as what you wanted.

```py
import pprint

# ...
    # ...
    for row in reading_file:
        if row[2] == postcode:
            output.append((row[1], row[4]))
    
    print("suburb, values")    
    pprint.pprint(output)
```

Output

```
suburb, values
[('Adelaide', 'Small_Animal'),
 ('Adelaide', 'Oncology'),
 ('Adelaide', 'Surgery'),
 ('Adelaide', 'Annual_Checkup'),
 ('Adelaide', 'Wildlife')]
```

Or, if you want the output to be table-like, try using formatted string literals/ `f-strings`.

```py
# ...
    # ...
    sub_width = val_width = 0
    for row in reading_file:
        if row[2] == postcode:
            output.append((row[1], row[4]))
       
            # calculate the minimum width of each column
            sub_width = len(row[1]) if len(row[1]) > sub_width else sub_width
            val_width = len(row[4]) if len(row[4]) > val_width else val_width


    print(f"+{'='*(sub_width+2)}+{'='*(val_width+2)}+")
    print(f"| {'Suburb':{sub_width}} | {'Service':{val_width}} |")
    print(f"+{'='*(sub_width+2)}+{'='*(val_width+2)}+")
    for row in output:
        print(f"| {row[0]:{sub_width}} | {row[1]:{val_width}} |")
        print(f"+{'-'*(sub_width+2)}+{'-'*(val_width+2)}+")
```

Output

```
+==========+================+
| Suburb   | Service        |
+==========+================+
| Adelaide | Small_Animal   |
+----------+----------------+
| Adelaide | Oncology       |
+----------+----------------+
| Adelaide | Surgery        |
+----------+----------------+
| Adelaide | Annual_Checkup |
+----------+----------------+
| Adelaide | Wildlife       |
+----------+----------------+
```

Alternatively, the output can also be fed to a `template` and returned as HTML table. You can pass any data you need to the `template` as template variables. You can name the variables whatever you want, as long as the template uses the same variable names.

```py
template(filepath, var1=data1, var2=data2, ...)
```

Assume you have the following project structure

```
project-name
 |-- views
 |    |-- index.tpl
 |  ...
 |-- main.py
```

Revise your Python script

```py
# ...
    # ...
    for row in reading_file:
        if row[2] == postcode:
            output.append((row[1], row[4]))

    return template('views/index.tpl', title="Available Vet Service", header=["Suburb", "Values"], rows=output)
```

Content of `index.tpl`

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link 
     rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
     integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            % for col_title in header:
              <th scope="col">{{col_title}}</th>
            % end
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          % for cell in rows:
            <tr>
              <td>{{cell[0]}}</td>
              <td>{{cell[1]}}</td>
            </tr>
          % end
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the screenshot of the HTML output.

[image: Output as HTML Table]

Comment: thanks for the answer but i needed to include the suburb, service with the data. So when I export this file as HTML document it gives me the head as suburb, services and data as the [('Adelaide', 'Small_Animal') and so on. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: I assume you are trying to use the `output` and feed it to HTML? If so, there are a few ways to achieve this. One of them is to use a template. I will add more details in the answer section and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for the answers, it working now

Answer (score 0):

If you want `output` to be a list of key-value pairs with suburb as the key and service as the value, then you should replace the lines

```
output.append(row[1])
output.append(row[4])
```

with just `output.append((row[1], row[4]))` so that `output` is a list of tuples.

Alternatively, you may want to make `output` a dictionary. To do this, replace your declaration `output = []` with `output = {}` and then replace the lines

```
output.append(row[1])
output.append(row[4])
```

with `output[row[1]] = row[4]`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. the result I'm getting from your corrections is:
[('Adelaide', 'Small_Animal'), 
('Adelaide', 'Oncology'), 
('Adelaide', 'Surgery'), 
('Adelaide', 'Annual_Checkup'), 
('Adelaide', 'Wildlife')]
but what i want it to be like: 

suburb, values
Adelaide', 'Small_Animal
Adelaide', 'Surgery
So kinda like the table and this is where I'm getting stuck, to show the suburb, values as the table columns.